# Joomla item level ACL issue - Permissions not working correctly

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, acl, joomla3.0

I have followed the [Joomla Docs tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_ACL) on how to add ACL to my custom component.
While I had success to add the component wide permission management I am struggeling to get the item level ACL to work.

I am trying to implement an ACL for the table `books`. I have added an `asset_id` column there as described in the tutorial.
I added a file `book.xml` in `admin/models/forms/` - this is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <field name="asset_id" type="hidden" filter="unset" />
    <field name="rules"
        type="rules"
        label="JFIELD_RULES_LABEL"
        translate_label="false"
        filter="rules"
        validate="rules"
        class="inputbox"
        component="com_mytest"
        section="book"
    />
</form>
```

This is how my `access.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access component="com_mytest">
        <section name="component">
                <action name="core.admin" title="JACTION_ADMIN" description="JACTION_ADMIN_COMPONENT_DESC" />
                <action name="core.manage" title="JACTION_MANAGE" description="JACTION_MANAGE_COMPONENT_DESC" />
                <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT_BOOK" description="COM_MYTEST_ACCESS_EDIT_BOOK_DESC" />
                <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE_BOOK" description="COM_MYTEST_ACCESS_DELETE_BOOK_DESC" />
        </section>
        <section name="book">
                <action name="core.edit" title="JACTION_EDIT_BOOK" description="COM_MYTEST_ACCESS_EDIT_BOOK_DESC" />
                <action name="core.delete" title="JACTION_DELETE_BOOK" description="COM_MYTEST_ACCESS_DELETE_BOOK_DESC" />
        </section>
</access>
```

In my JTable variant in `admin/tables/mytest_books.php` I have added this methods:

```
public function bind($array, $ignore = '')
{               
    if (isset($array['jform']) && isset($array['jform']['rules']) && is_array($array['jform']['rules']))
    {
        $rules = new JAccessRules($array['jform']['rules']);
        $this->setRules($rules);
    }
    return parent::bind($array, $ignore);
}

protected function _getAssetName()
{
    return 'com_mytest.book.'.(int) $this->id;
}

protected function _getAssetTitle()
{
    return $this->name;
}

protected function _getAssetParentId()
{
    $asset = JTable::getInstance('Asset');
    $asset->loadByName('com_mytest');
    return $asset->id;
}
```

As you might notice in the `bind()` method above I have to extract the `rules` array from with in the `jform` array. In all tutorials I saw they simply reference `$array['rules']` and not `$array['jform']['rules']`.

**Maybe this is my issue?**

This is my book model `admin/models/book.php`:

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
    $form = $this->loadForm('com_mytest.book', 'book', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));          
    if (empty($form)){
        return false;
    }           
    return $form;
}

protected function loadFormData()
{
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_mytest.edit.book.data', array());
    if (empty($data))
    {
        $data = $this->getItem($this->_id);
    }
    return $data;           
}
```

Here is what I added at the bottom in the book editing screen `admin/views/book/tmpl/default.php`:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.start', 'permissions-sliders-'.$this->row->id, array('useCookie'=>1)); ?>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.panel', JText::_('COM_MYTEST_FIELDSET_RULES'), 'access-rules'); ?>
            <fieldset class="panelform">
                <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('rules'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('rules'); ?>
            </fieldset>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.end'); ?>
```

**Here is what is working:**

When I save a book after editing the book level ACL for a group the settings save correctly. My asset table looks good, showing entries like:

> id   | name              | title | rules
>
> 198   | com_mytest.book.2 | The guide to something | {"core.edit":{"1":0,"6":1,"7":1,"2":0,"3":0,"4":1,"5":0,"10":0,"12":0,"8":0},"core.delete":{"1":0,"6":1,"7":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"10":0,"12":0,"8":0}}

And yes, the book with ID 2 has 198 in the `asset_id` column.

**Here is my problem**

When I save the book ACL by setting *Allowed* for all actions for the *Administrator* user group the dialog shows ***Conflict*** beside the permission. Setting everything to *Denied* does not show this message.

**For the *Allowed* case (and the *Conflict*-situation):**

When I use a second browser to login as an *Administrator* user group user this condition always returns false (yes, `$row->id` does contain a valid ID):

> $canEdit = JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit',
>   'com_mytest.book.'.$row->id);

Can you help me solving this puzzle?

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0):

Are your book assets getting the correct parent id in the asset table? 
Any time you use ACL when not using categories you need to be extremely careful about parenting. Usually you want to ensure that the items are getting the component as the parent.
This is something that is a bit messy in the classes, but you can look at com_modules and see how this can work. 
A conflict situation exists when a group has a hard deny somewhere between the item and the the start of the branch. Usually that might be denied on a component but allowed for a category of that component, as one example.  You can get into a conflict situation if your parenting is not done correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your input on my question. I understand that there might be a hard deny somewhere up the hierarchy. Can you provide me with some tips how to debug the parenting?

Comment: Look in the asset table and see what the parent_id is and then check if it matches the id of your component in the asset table.  Most likely you are not parenting correctly and hence there is no default soft deny and hence you have a hard deny.

Comment: Sorry for taking this long. I checked and the parent_id is set to the correct ID of my component in the asset table. Now I feel pretty helpless. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: A further idea: does every contact need ACL on a category level? My books have / need no category at all.

Comment: No, you don't need to have an asset, if you don't need an asset then make sure your jtable class says assets are not supported and that you do not have an asset_id field in your table.

Comment: Sorry, but now I am confused. What do you mean I do not have to have an asset? I assume every book has an entry in the assets table while the parent_id of the rows links to the assets table's entry for the component. My previous question was just whether category ACL might be checked somehow (although I don't use/implement categories).

Comment: If you don't use categories then you don't use categories but you need to make sure that you write your jtable class to work without categories (this is a really common mistake because people copy the core which uses categories).  No, you do not need to have assets for books, it's totally up to you to decide if you need such specific permissions or if the component level will work for you. Or you can use categories to assign permissions to a group of books. The main purpose of categories architecturally is for working with hierarchically organized groups of items which is simpler than items.